# not able to compile with nvcc

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I've installed CUDA on debian,i've successfully ran make file in C folder withing cuda folder.but whn i'm trying to run individual file like matMult.cu with nvcc i'm getting following error
error:matrixMult.cu:no such file or directory
error:cutil_inline:no such file or directory

n also it is complaining about other header files...please help me out

Answer (score 1):

The CUDA SDK examples use a custom makefile based on rules defined in a common.mk file. In order to compile individually the examples you can make use of that Makefiles which can be tuning to add more dependencies or extra info.

To compile the matrixMul example by hand using the nvcc compiler, for an architecture of 64 bits and a Fermi device you can use:

> g++ -Wall -m64 -fno-strict-aliasing -I. -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I../../common/inc -I../../../shared//inc -DUNIX -O2  -o obj/x86_64/release/matrixMul_gold.cpp.o -c matrixMul_gold.cpp
>   /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -m64 --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing  -I. -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I../../common/inc -I../../../shared//inc -DUNIX -O2   -o obj/x86_64/release/matrixMul.cu.o -c matrixMul.cu
>
> g++ -m64 -o ../../bin/linux/release/matrixMul obj/x86_64/release/matrixMul_gold.cpp.o  obj/x86_64/release/matrixMul.cu.o  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L../../lib -L../../common/lib/linux -L../../../shared//lib -lcudart     -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L../../lib -L../../common/lib/linux -L../../../shared//lib -lcudart -lcutil_x86_64 -lshrutil_x86_64

Compile the CUDA SDK examples by hand it's a little weary. I recommend you use the makefile of each example or start a new project from the scratch.